# Is anyone successfully running SpamAssassin on Ubuntu Server 18.10?

Tags: server, spamassassin

I'm trying to build an email server based on Ubuntu, and I want to run SpamAssassin on it.  I've followed the instructions, installed it from the repositories, and when I try to start SpamAssassin I get an error message like the following:

```
Job for spamassassin.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

See "systemctl status spamassassin.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Running `sudo systemctl status spamassassin.service` gets me the following:

```
Feb 02 01:43:46 grace systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Feb 02 01:43:46 grace systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 02 01:43:46 grace systemd[1]: Stopped Perl-based spam filter using text analysis.
Feb 02 01:43:46 grace systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 02 01:43:46 grace systemd[1]: spamassassin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 02 01:43:46 grace systemd[1]: Failed to start Perl-based spam filter using text analysis.
```

I've tried stopping the service and starting it as well as simply restarting it, but it doesn't make a difference.  I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: Not anough info. Please add the output of `grep spamd /var/log/mail.log` (consider adding yourself to the `adm` group so you can read logs without `sudo`).

Comment: Okay, here's a sample of mail.log:

Feb  3 08:03:32 grace spamd[10234]: logger: removing stderr method
Feb  3 08:03:32 grace spamd[10236]: config: no rules were found! Do you need to run 'sa-update'?
Feb  3 08:03:33 grace spamd[10234]: child process [10236] exited or timed out without signaling production of a PID file: exit 255 at /usr/sbin/spamd line 3034.

So I ran sa-update (I was too impatient to let it finish before -- my bad) but it exits with code 4, meaning it can't find the rules.  I've tried a couple of other channels, but no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are following [this Ars Technica guide](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-3-fortifying-your-box-against-spammers/2/), then you probably have `/etc/default/spamassassin` looking like this:

```
SAHOME="/var/lib/spamassassin"
SAGLOBALCFGPATH="/etc/spamassassin"

# Change to one to enable spamd
ENABLED=1

# Options
# See man spamd for possible options. The -d option is automatically added.
OPTIONS="-x --max-children 5 --helper-home-dir ${SAHOME} -u spamd -g spamd --siteconfigpath ${SAGLOBALCFGPATH} --socketpath=/var/spool/postfix/spamassassin/spamd.sock --socketowner=spamd --socketgroup=spamd --socketmode=0660"

# Pid file
# Where should spamd write its PID to file? If you use the -u or
# --username option above, this needs to be writable by that user.
# Otherwise, the init script will not be able to shut spamd down.
PIDFILE="/var/run/spamd.pid"

# Cronjob
# Set to anything but 0 to enable the cron job to automatically update
# spamassassin's rules on a nightly basis
CRON=1
```

The path expansions of `SAHOME` and `SAGLOBALCFGPATH` are failing, so change this file so that it includes the full paths:

```
# Change to one to enable spamd
ENABLED=1

# Options
# See man spamd for possible options. The -d option is automatically added.
OPTIONS="-x --max-children 5 --helper-home-dir /var/lib/spamassassin -u spamd -g spamd --siteconfigpath /etc/spamassassin --socketpath=/var/spool/postfix/spamassassin/spamd.sock --socketowner=spamd --socketgroup=spamd --socketmode=0660"

# Pid file
# Where should spamd write its PID to file? If you use the -u or
# --username option above, this needs to be writable by that user.
# Otherwise, the init script will not be able to shut spamd down.
PIDFILE="/var/run/spamd.pid"

# Cronjob
# Set to anything but 0 to enable the cron job to automatically update
# spamassassin's rules on a nightly basis
CRON=1
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!

Comment: Hello, @KenWright, if [this] answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) (by click on the grey tick ✓ left to it) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: I didn't know that.  Thank you!

Comment: The better answer is for OP to follow a better guide. For instance:  
You do not need a `spamd` user. Please review this - it's debian/ubuntu repo-friendlier: https://gist.github.com/bmatthewshea/2acd4126b163216f2cefd605609befc8